# iPhone UIWebView problem

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to write an application to show a web page in a web view for this link: 
http://just4u.safeway.com
But the page can not be shown in the UiWebView, I got a message:

> This page contains the following
>   errors: error on line 90 at column 11:
>   AttValue: " or ' expected.

Can someone let me know what could be the problem? I already added code to handle redirect, but still get the same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting the MIME type of the page to be "text/html". Otherwise it may be parsed in the UIWebview as xhtml. Also check that your `<!DOCTYPE>` is not claiming to be xhtml.

Comment: Here is the <!DOCTYPE> in the web page: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">. So is it XHTML? I tried to download the page to a NSData and called [self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"; but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a very similar problem. 
I was using the loadRequest method of UIWebView, which was causing the UIWebView to interpret it as XHTML. 
I instead used NSURLConnection to asynchronously load the data for the webpage, then used

```
[webView loadData:downloadedData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pageURLString]];
```

and got the page to display without the pink error box at the top.

This is essentially the same solution as PengOne suggests - I just wanted to confirm that the suggestion works fine, and show the sample code that worked for me.